# I need to add a print option in the display form page

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I need to add a print option in the display form page. It should redirect me to print page option. help me using script or designer. Custom coding is not allowed for me to do

Answer (score 2):

Add a content editor webpart to the page, and in the HTML of it add something like this:

```
<a href="javascript:window.print()">Print</a>
```

or just add it to the page with SP Designer

Comment: I tried to do so...but nothing is happened except page loading...is there any feature i need to activate?

Comment: This is not SharePoint functionality, this is plain JavaScript. Might be that your browsers security settings are stopping the script. Check the developer tools (F12 - click Console) for errors

Comment: scrip is working fine...but "print" functionality is not working..

Answer (score 0):

The code given below will work with sharepoint ASPX pages and with any browser.
Add a content editor webpart to the page and add the below code in the HTML of the webpart.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       function printPartOfPage(elementId) {
        var printContent = document.getElementById(elementId);
        var windowUrl = '';
        var uniqueName = new Date();
        var windowName = 'Print' ;
        var printWindow = window.open(windowUrl, windowName, 'left=-20,top=-20,width=0,height=0');
        printWindow.document.write('<HTML><Head><Title></Title>');
        printWindow.document.write('</Head><Body style="margin-left:50px;margin-top:50px;font-size:10pt;">');
        printWindow.document.write(printContent.innerHTML);
        printWindow.document.write('</Body></HTML>');
        printWindow.document.close();
        printWindow.focus();
        printWindow.print();
        printWindow.close();
    }
</script>
```

you can use an Print button with Click event and call the above javascript function.

```
<img alt="" src="ImageSource" 
onclick="JavaScript:printPartOfPage('YourDivClientID');" />
```

For more ideas, please refer the below links,

1. https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/SharePoint-List-New-Custom-Action-Using-SharePoint-Designer.aspx
2. http://blogs.ibs.com/Scott.Zischerk/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=13

Answer (score 0):

To add a print button to your form,

Please review this article

[Add Print button](http://sabinatechdiary.blogspot.in/2015/08/add-print-button-to-sharepoint-infopath.html)

Regards,

Sabby

Comment: Please provide more information or quotes from the article.